# Does my roof have soffit ventilation and do I need to install baffles prior to blowing in insulation?

Tags: insulation, roof, attic

**Edit**: As it turns out, my soffit vents are decorative only. I pried open the soffit in 2 different areas, and there is continuous solid wood behind it. **How is the attic getting ventilated then?**

Because I am rewiring my house, I had a contractor remove insulation from the attic. The contractor mostly left the insulation intact in the soffit areas. I am trying to establish two things:

1. Does my roof have soffit ventilation? If so, why were the batts stuffed all the way inside the soffit?
2. Do I need to install soffit baffles? The clearance is extremely limited. In fact, I cannot do it from inside the attic. I could not even insert the baffle in the cavity, much less put it in its place.

#### [Pictures with descriptions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkGW7.jpg)

1. Roof structure (1950s Ranch Style Home in the Rocky Mountains of USA)
2. Soffit under the eaves extending past the wall
3. Soffit grill structure details
4. Attic ventilation details
5. Eave bay 1 showing end of drywall and beginning of soffit area.
6. Eave bay 2 showing insulation batt stuffed in the soffit area.

Answer (score 1):

Some idiot did the insulation, should not be/not needed any insulation blocking the soffits.

Insulation only needed/wanted over the living sections of a house.

Baffles or some kind of stop, a piece of wood/tin nailed along the rafters at the floor, to prevent insulation blocking the soffits.

Comment: I just pried soffit in a couple of areas where there is appearance of vent grill and there is solid wood behind them. So I don't have soffit ventilation. Does it make sense then that there should be insulation in that area? How is the attic being ventilated if there are no soffit vents?

Comment: Will need to add vents.  Either by cutting holes in the wood or removing it.  Ventilation of the roof is quite important for long lasting roofs.